# function to return 50 random number php

Tags: php

How can I generate a 6 digit random number? On every page refresh code will be change. So create function on every page refresh create new random number.

Dont want to use predefined function. Not use php predefined php function like rand , mt_rand

Comment: Then you are going to have to write your own function.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an existing function? Creating anything that can reliably handle "random" is EXTREMELY hard, hence these libraries exist.

Comment: If you're going to say you don't want to use a standard function then you need to explain _why_. Otherwise we don't know what your special requirement is which would justify using a different approach.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for a bit of help with your homework. Beginners are welcome, but we expect a good faith attempt at an answer from you first. 
___SO is not a free coding service___ although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 3):

Generating random numbers isn't easy - if you'd like to understand why, see below:

[https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/random_numbers.html](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/random_numbers.html)

`rand()` (As of PHP 7.1.0, rand() uses the same random number generator as mt_rand()) is the best way in PHP to get a simple random number.

If this is for cryptographic reasons, then use `random_int()`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php

For a 6-digit number as requested:

```
<?php
rand(100000, 999999);
```

OR

```
<?php
random_int(100000, 999999);
```